# Group datafrime by time slots in Pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

i'm working with a dataset that comes from the data sent by underground sensors stations, which provide an estimate of the flow of the cars going through them.
My data are grouped by hour for each sensor on the same period of time,
this is how the df looks like:

[image]

I thought to find some trends of the flow in various time slots( like morning, afternoon, evening, night)

My question is:

there's a way to group the data for each station_id in time slots?
For example group the data of each station from 00:00 to 06:00, from 06:00 to 12:00 and so on, and for every subgroup calculate the mean of the flow value.

Concerning the time i'm interested in keeping for each time slot only the day and the month

I've read the datetime's documentation and tried with some methods but unsuccessfully

I'll appreciate everyone who'll reply and help me with any tip.

Comment: if you could post data that could be copied or repreduced it will make it much easier to answer, at any rate you could add a column of timestamp rounded to 6 hours and groupby by it

Comment: Of course, here the link to download the dataset in csv format https://www.4shared.com/file/WfG9vD27iq/readings_by_hour.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create the bins and group by them:

```
df = pd.read_csv('readings_by_hour.csv')
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df['time_bins'] = df['time'].dt.floor('6h')
df.groupby(['station_id', 'time_bins'])['flow'].mean()
```